# Setting IIS server to use the “Content-Security-Policy” header

Tags: iis, web-config, xss, content-security-policy

I currently have the Content-Security-Policy set on my IIS as the following:

add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self'"

With this option it is blocking content on pages that have iframe embedded. I don't want to remove this policy since it is there to help against Cross-Scripting Attacks. What would be the best approach to set so it does it's job but allows iframes. I had to remove X-Frame-Options too because of this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Edit the question to include extra information, not leaving comments.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe elements have a csp attribute which specifies the policy that an embedded document must agree to enforce upon itself. Valid attribute values match the serialized-policy grammar from [CSP3].

More information you can refer to this link: [Content Security Policy: Embedded Enforcement](https://www.w3.org/TR/csp-embedded-enforcement).

Comment: What would be best option to use if pages are embedded into an iframe? we want to use this policy but still allow iframes.

Comment: It is impossible if you want to use iframe and this policy at the same time.